# SQL stored procedure duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have duplicate records and I would like to add 1 in the 1st record and 0 for all duplicate records how can I acheive that. ?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and stored procedures are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TSQL ROW\_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY... ORDER BY....)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47317424/tsql-row-number-over-partition-by-order-by)

Comment: I'm using SQL server ms sql

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is getting down-voted because it doesn't include enough detail. Please take a moment to read these two links, then consider editing your question if you're still looking for help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: It is always helpful to paste an example of data, especially if other users can cut and paste it to test your issue from or provide relevant answers against.

Comment: Please provide more detail and I might be able to help you. Perhaps a code snippet of the stored proc you are running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
UPDATE t1
SET [Column1] = IIF(sub.[RowNumber] = 1, 1, 0)
FROM Table1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT [ID], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Column2] ORDER BY [ID]) AS [RowNumber]
        FROM Table1
    ) AS sub
        ON sub.[ID] = t1.[ID];

--[Column1] For Update
--[Column2] Your Duplicates
```